# Is it possible to apply partial text formatting to an svg string?

Tags: html, css, svg

Is it possible to partially underline an svg text element?

The HTML  tags allow for this in HTML, how do I achieve the same effect in an SVG text element?

If I write "`We want <u>more</u> of this sort of thing`", "more" is underlined.

Is there a way to do this with svg?

`<text x="150" y="100">We want </text><text text-decoration="underline">more</text><text> of this sort of thing</text>` gives me "We want " correctly displayed, but the other 2 text elements are located at x="0", y="0".

Presumably, If I want these to display as the same sentence, I need to calculate the position of the x and y coordinates and position them accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `<tspan>` within the `<text>` together with `text-decoration="underline"`.

```
<svg width="500" height="500">
    <text x="150" y="100">
    We want <tspan text-decoration="underline">more</tspan> of this sort of thing</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`<tspan>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan).

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
<text x="150" y="100">We want <tspan text-decoration="underline">more</tspan> of this sort of thing</text>
</svg>
```